# Determine the largest magnitude and the angle of a force applied at a point

Tags: trigonometry, physics

The following problem comes from "Vector Mechanics for Engineers: Statics" from F.Beer
[image]

The solution goes on with law of cosines to find $P$ for item (a) and law of sines to find $\beta$ and then find $\alpha$ for item (b). What I don't understand is why the angle between the $600$N and $1200$N forces is $85°$, I thought it should be $180°-35°-50°=95°$. So, I want to know why the angle between the tension forces is their sum and not what I've thought in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the force diagram, the arrows are placed so that they follow each other. This is because the total vector sum is zero since the system is in equilibrium.

Comment: So we put a parallel line to the shown horizontal line, and translate $T_{BC}$ force to the head of arrow of $T_{AC}$, and the angle between then must be $50° + 30$? since $35°$ its an alternate interior angle.

Comment: Yes that’s right